# Unable to Ping over wifi

Tags: ip, wifi, ping, connection, ethernet

We have 2 PCs and 4 laptops in the office, and we use D-Link 2750U to connect to internet. All the computers can connect to the internet successfully.

One thing that I noticed recently, is that PCs (with Ethernet cables) are not able to ping laptops (with wireless connections). Also, the wireless laptops are not able to ping wired PCs.

For example, the IP of PC1 is 192.168.1.33 and the IP of laptop1 is 192.168.1.36. The following are the ping results from both devices trying to ping each other:

[The PC trying to ping the Laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRqdw.jpg)

[The Laptop trying to ping the PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZbet.jpg)

***Why is this problem happening?***

***What should I do solve this problem?***

Your time and help is appreciated.

***P.S. 1***

The PCs ping each other successfully.

***P.S. 2***

If we connect the laptops with Ethernet cables (not wireless), the ping is successful; i.e. the PCs can ping laptops, and also the laptops can ping PCs with successful responds.

Comment: Why do you need to be able to ping the laptops from the PCs and vice versa? What actual problem is this causing? What actual problem do you need to solve?

Comment: Thanks @joeqwerty for your comment. The actual problem is that wireless clients are not able to join the server domain. I searched a lot, and found this actual problem, which prevents wireless clients from joining the domain. So I need to solve this issue.

Comment: Umm... yeah... not so much. The inability to ping isn't in and of itself the cause of the problem. It may be a symptom of the real problem, like maybe the wireless clients are using a different subnet mask from the wired clients, effectively putting them in a different subnet and rendering them unable to communicate with the wired clients and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks again @joeqwerty for your helpful points. Actually, I solved this problem by disabling the ***MultiAP Isolation*** from modem's wireless settings. Thanks.